# Netlogo : spawning a turtle on a certain patch with a certain pcolor

Tags: patch, netlogo

I'm working on a Simulation of a Stadion. I have created several rows with `pcolor = 35`. 
Now I need my number of turtles to spawn on the patches with `pcolor = 35`, but nowhere else. They also need to spawn randomly on those patches.
My code for this problem looks like this:

```
to seat-people

set color green

setxy int random-xcor int random-ycor

if (pcolor = 35) [seat-people]

if any? other turtles-here [seat-people]

end
```

The turtles are green, spawn randomly and there is only one turtle per patch;
but they won't spawn on patches with `pcolor = 35` but everywhere! How do I do that?

I've seen a code with `if (pcolor > 35) [seat-people]`,
but I already have many other pcolors < and > than 35.

Answer (score 2):

try with this. where `N` is the number of turtle you want to sprout and `sprout 1` is the procedure to sprout 1 turtle which you can modify as you want.

```
ask n-of N patches with [pcolor = 35 and not any? other turtles-here][sprout 1]
```

Comment: If I replace N with the slider for the number of turtles, what is the sprout 1 for? I used your code and not a single turtle appeared.

Comment: I tested my code and it's working. if you replace N with a number (let's say 20) what you are doing is: ask to 20 patches (chosen with a certain condition) to sprout 1 turtle on it. So 20 turtles in total. Now reading again your question I don't get if you want turtles spawned on green or on other colors. My code sprout turtles on green, if I understood wrong you just have to replace '= 35' with '!= 35'

Comment: It works now, I had to change some parts of my own code for it to work, but it works! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the 'not equal' operator !=

```
 Ask n-of 20 patches with [pcolor != 35][sprout 1]
```

Comment: I don't know if I can use n-of 20 patches, since the number of patches shouldn't affect the simulation, but I tried your code and a combination of yours and mine and it didn't work. When I replace = 35 with != 35, the screen goes black and turtles seem to randomly run around as if not able to be placed.

Comment: In addition, if I say "ask patches with [pcolor = 35] [sprout 1] then every single patch with pcolor 35 sprouts a turtle which results in about 600 turtles spawning. And if I use !=35, then EVERY patch spawns a turtle and the screen is full of turtles. :-D

Comment: There seems to be a language barrier.